# Minimum hardware requirements for using erlang as a developer

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have made a small erlang project and I am now making its documentation. I am not able to find the answer to the question that what would be the **minimum** requirements for using erlang as far as these **three parameters are concerned**.

1) Micro Processor

2) Cache Memory

3) Hard Disk

Can any one help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need all of those.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such a list. It would depend on every program and usage.

Comment: yes I know that I need all these but actually I wanted to know that what would be the specifications of a microprocessor below which erlang language cannot be used by a developer. Same for minimum cache memory required and hard disk space(min) required.

Comment: You can run it on a [raspberry pi](https://www.slideshare.net/breakpointer/using-erlang-on-the-raspberrypi), so shouldn't need much to get started.

Answer (score 2):

See http://erlang.org/faq/implementations.html - in particular the bottom of the page. Regarding disk, Erlang can even run in a diskless system, loading code over the network. Not sure if by "cache memory" you mean the CPU cache or if you are referring to RAM in general, but there are no particular requirements on CPU cache size, and even as little as 16-32 MB RAM can be sufficient.

Comment: got it,Thank you for helping.